# making logical inference from a simuation generated data

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining

I have data collected from a computer simulation of football games which seem to have recurring patterns of the following form.

*if madrid plays arsernal and the match ends under 3 goal, then on their next match against each others, madrid will win. if madrid happens to loose and then plays against chelsea next, they will win 90% of the time.*

how do I find such inferences from simulation generated data like this. There are other forms of hidden patterns that I believe exists in the dataset.

Comment: You really can't draw inferences from *simulated* data, and, in most cases, not even from real data. Since you have so many parameters to play with, you will always (through sheer chance) find some "pattern" that doesn't really exist.

Comment: @user4710 - i disagree.  You can't draw inferences about real football, but you can draw plenty of inferences about video-game football.  This sounds like they want a random-forest fit, then they want to make a single-cart approximation of the random forest, and look at the splits and decision points for probability of win.

Comment: Is this a reasonable dataset for an example solution?  https://github.com/jmerullo/football

Answer (score 0):

Define a specific environmental state (e.g., madrid plays arsernal and the match ends under 3 goal), then run the simulation many times each time with a random seed. The result will be a distribution of simulated outcomes. Summary statistics can be computed on the distribution of outcomes.